# Enumeration Interface and vector Class

Tags: java, oop, vector, enumeration

I am deeply confused about the Enumeration interface an vector class. I know there aren't used for storing and searching now a days but still was interested in them.

Facts I know:

1. Vector class implements Enumeration interface and thus its method `hasMoreElements()` and `nextElement()`.
2. Vector class has a method `elements()` that returns an object of Vector class therefore has its return type of Enumeration.

Thing I am Confused about:

Suppose `Vector vec=new Vector(2,3)`;
`vec.elements().nextElement()` gives me desired object whereas just `vec.nextElement()` is undefined though Vector class actually implements Enumeration Interface so why can't its object directly access the overridden methods.

Comment: Where did you see that `Vector` implements `Enumeration`?

Comment: I have read it in a book. If thats not the case then how come you have Enumeration vec.elements()

Comment: Vector was replaced by ArrayList in 1998. You should be able to answer your own question by reading the code if you are really interested.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [JAVA DOC of  Vector](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Vector.html) class  shows that implemented interfaces in this class are `Serializable, Cloneable, Iterable<E>, Collection<E>, List<E>, RandomAccess`

The Vector's `elements()` method signature is: `public Enumeration<E> elements()` calling
Which returns an `instance of implemented Enumeration` as is evident from following source code:

```
public Enumeration<E> elements() {
        return new Enumeration<E>() {  // return implemented enumeration
            int count = 0;

            public boolean hasMoreElements() {
                return count < elementCount;
            }

            public E nextElement() {  // implementing nextElement
                synchronized (Vector.this) {
                    if (count < elementCount) {
                        return elementData(count++); 
                          // accessing vector elements data which 
                         //traverses an array of object
                    }
                }
                throw new NoSuchElementException("Vector Enumeration");
            }
        };
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

`Vecotr` class does not implement `Enumeration`. Where did you see that, can you share source of you information.

```
public class Vector<E>
extends AbstractList<E>
implements List<E>, RandomAccess, Cloneable, java.io.Serializable
```

Further, none of the the class or interface implement or extend `Enumeration` interface.

Comment: If thats not the case then what is the significance of this line Enumeration vec.elements()

Comment: that means elements method of Vector class will return Enumeration object. That's it.

Comment: @chetanmehta, i have already showed you how the `elements()` function work.